# How to put all console output in a file but also display it on console C#?

Tags: c#, console, output

How I do this in C#? I know about Console.SetOut() and it's not what i want since i get nothing on my console and everything goes to file. How I do to make both write in text file and display on Console? Is there any smart way or I need to go the hard and tedious route of Check file exists, Open File, Write, Close File after each Console.WriteLine() function

Comment: Just write your own function that receives a string and then output that to both the Console and your Log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple logger class:

```
class Logger {
    string LogFilePath { get; set; }

    void WriteLine(string msg) {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(LogFilePath, msg + '\n');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var logger = new Logger { LogFilePath = "text file path" };
logger.WriteLine("Write this to the console and append to the logfile");
```

Comment: Implemented this before you wrote the answer, but yes indeed this is a good way to solve the problem. Tought there is another smart way already implemented in .Net Framework that I did not know about. Thanks for the response and I hope other find it usefull too